# How to group columns based on specific text and sum them using ORACLE database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a newbie in oracle. Trying to group columns based on a specific text and sum other columns.

let's say I have below tables

[image]

I want to group by all people with the last name. Like below

[image]

I have no clue how should I proceed.
Note: There could be multiple names but I just want to filter for Sharma, Decosta and Liver.

Updating the question.
Sorry for updating the question. but in a real scenario search string is not always at last.

Let me give you another example.
[image: c]

Output.

[image]

Comment: How do you determine what the last name is? What if it's a [double-barrelled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name)? Probably better to split the `Name` column into two columns, namely `First_Name` and `Last_Name`.

Comment: Unfortunately that not the real data. I have string i  need to find based on some keyword. So i cant split it

Comment: Does _Dog gone dogs_ count as one occurrence of dog or two? Does _Dogs can't use pens_ count as one occurrence of dog and one of pen? What about _Sean Penn traveled through Pennsylvania without penalty until he reached the penultimate mile_ How many **pen**s are there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+$') as last_name, sum(num_beers)
from t
group by regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+$');
```

Comment: It should be sum. Right ?

Comment: I get the result below its not summing it. LAST_NAME COUNT

Decosta 1
Decosta   1
Sharma 2
Liver        1
Sharma    1

Comment: Correct it should be sum. I was trying to do that  select last_name, sum(count) from
(
select regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+$') as last_name, count(*) as count
from beer
group by regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+$')
)group by last_name;  but dint help

Comment: @Varun, Did you try the solution I posted ? Is it working fine ?

Comment: @Ranagal . . . Yes, that should be `sum()` and now is.

Answer (score 0):

The queries offered so far does seem to work to get what you need. But the below does:

```
With inputs as
(
    select 'Rahul Kumar Sharma' as Name, 10 as No_of_beer_bottles from dual union all
    select 'Rohith Kumar Sharma' as Name, 5 as No_of_beer_bottles from dual union all
    select 'Sharma' as Name, 20 as No_of_beer_bottles from dual union all
    select 'Rahul Kumar Varma' as Name, 10 as No_of_beer_bottles from dual
)
select  SUBSTR(name,Instr(name,' ',-1)+1) as Name, sum(No_of_beer_bottles) as No_of_beer_bottles
from    inputs
group by SUBSTR(name,Instr(name,' ',-1)+1);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks for the ans. It works for the given question however unfortunately in the real scenario it is not that the last name would occur at last. basically I created the dummy date. In a nutshell, I have a string, and I need to search columns based on that string and sum there value. the search string is given.

Comment: @Varun, Ok. How do you know what you have to extract and make it as a name ? If you have rules. Tell us, we will try.

Comment: That is a predefined word, In the above example pen and dog

Answer (score 0):

If you use have a table with all the words you are searching for (or define them in a Common Table Expression like I did below), you can join on that search term then sum the numeric column.

#### Query 1

```
WITH
    search_words (word)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Sharma' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Decosta' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Liver' FROM DUAL),
    d (name, num_beers)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Ravi Sharma', 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Sam Decosta', 4 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Jhony Liver', 5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Ravi Sharma', 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Rohul Sharma', 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Jhon Decosta', 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'V Decosta', 3 FROM DUAL)
  SELECT sw.word, SUM (d.num_beers) AS total_beer
    FROM search_words sw, d
   WHERE INSTR (UPPER (d.name), UPPER (sw.word)) > 0
GROUP BY sw.word;
```

#### Result 1

```
      WORD    TOTAL_BEER
__________ _____________
Decosta               10
Sharma                 6
Liver                  5
```

#### Query 2

```
WITH
    search_words (word)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Pen' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Dog' FROM DUAL),
    d (name, quantity)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Ravi have red pens', 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Sam''s grifriend have black dogs', 4 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Jhony has blue pen', 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Ravi has white dog', 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Rahul has small dogs', 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'There are pens inside Jhon''s car', 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'My dog and me are flying.', 1 FROM DUAL)
  SELECT sw.word, SUM (d.quantity) AS total_quantity
    FROM search_words sw, d
   WHERE INSTR (UPPER (d.name), UPPER (sw.word)) > 0
GROUP BY sw.word;
```

#### Result 2

```
   WORD    TOTAL_QUANTITY
_______ _________________
Dog                     9
Pen                     6
```